# Winamp jump dialog

Tags: winamp

In the most recent build of Winamp, either the Jump dialog has been *ruined* or there's some hidden "advanced" setting that i'm missing.

The Jump dialog used to have a few options, like

"Jump to file and play"

"Jump to file without playing"

*"Queue file to start playing next, after this song finishes"*

But now it only shows (CANCEL) as the only button, and you can press enter on a file to start play.

What happened to the JUMP & QUEUE feature? I want to jump to a file, but QUEUE it to be played next, not play it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, those buttons were part of an extended Jump plugin. I was more of a fan of the simple jump dialog, so I always removed the extended one, so I'm not 100% sure of the name. I think [this may be it](http://nunzioweb.com/daz/jtfe.html), but I can't check because I'm currently at work...